# Azure Notification Hub - Registering from Mobile apps and Sending notifications via App back end

Tags: azure, push-notification, notifications

I'm planning to register devices from mobile app using tag account no (this is unique per account with more than one device linked to an account). This is done using Azure Notification Hub SDK on mobile app (Android and iOS).

Following registration, send notifications targeting account numbers from application back end (.Net application) to notification hub. Is this a correct approach? I'm assuming we follow a common template for all PNS servers (Apple and Google) when the notification is sent to hub.

Can you please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking question! To Integrate Azure Notification Hubs into mobile apps you can follow below steps:

1. Set up Push Notification Services and Azure Notification Hub.
2. Use Register templates and tags with the Azure Notification Hub.
3. Create a cross-platform Xamarin.Forms application.
4. Configure the native Android project for push notifications.
5. Configure the native iOS project for push notifications.
6. Test notifications using the Azure Notification Hub.
7. Create a backend application to send notifications.

To add to this, Push notifications deliver information from a backend system to a mobile application. Apple, Google, and other platforms each have their own Push Notification Service (PNS).

Azure Notification Hubs enable you to centralize notifications across platforms so your backend application can communicate with a single hub, which takes care of distributing the notifications to each platform-specific PNS.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-notification-hub